# Tomar foto sin abrir cámara

Tags: android

Buenas a todos, quisiera obtener un ejemplo o alguna idea para tomar una fotografía sin necesidad de abrir la cámara, la idea es tener un botón en la aplicación y al momento de pulsarlo se tome una foto y sea guardada.

Comment: No sé si eso es posible pero ¿esto no genera un problema de seguridad? Imagina que luego pueda llamar al método del botón programáticamente y tomar la foto, de manera que si luego coloco un agente en el dispositivo podría ejecutar una funcionalidad similar y enviar las fotos ni bien tenga conexión a internet y publicarlas en sitios externos, y gratis y sin consentimiento del usuario.

Comment: Aquí hay unos ejemplos que podrían servirte (en inglés): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462360/android-use-camera-without-surfaceview-or-textureview/22468306#22468306, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684553/how-to-take-pictures-from-the-camera-without-preview-when-my-app-starts

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza por eso tienes que declarar un permiso en el manifest para tener acceso a la cámara, y el usuario debe dar su consentimiento cuando instalas la aplicación.

Comment: Hola Cesar, yo una vez lo hice para Windows Phone y no me aprobaron el App, si es para el Google Play, quiza no valga la pena hacerlo ya que probablemente sea rechazada o denuncida.

Comment: @Carlos Muñoz, si no estoy mal, la idea para el grupo en español es dar una respuesta, así sea tomada de Stack en inglés, desde que se traduzca completamente y se responda como traducción del otro sitio, con referencia y todo.

Comment: @SalahAdDin Es por eso que no lo publiqué como respuesta. En primer lugar no programo para Android, en segundo lugar no tenía mucho tiempo de investigar más el tema. Es solo un comentario que espero sea de ayuda para César, para otro usuario que entre en el futuro o para alguien que tenga el tiempo y conocimiento para publicar una respuesta apropiada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me imagino quieres tomar fotos estilo espía, desde la API 11 (Android Honeycomb) se puede realizar pero por medio de [***SurfaceTexture***](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html) :

```
mCamera = Camera.open();
SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(10);
mCamera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
```

Recuerda agregar el feature requerido en el `Manifest.xml`

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

y los permisos

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Revisa esta pregunta:(inglés)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20741300/250260